# QCache and std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, smart-pointers

Can someone give me please a hint for this error:

```
no viable conversion from 'std::shared_ptr<Foo>' to 'std::__1::shared_ptr<Foo> *'
```

The QCache looks like this:

```
QCache<int, std::shared_ptr<Foo>> cache;
```

And I try to insert the element like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo;
cache.insert(23, foo);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: From the error it seems like `QCache` wants a pointer to it's stored type, not the type itself.

Comment: Thanks. It compiles now as a reference with: cache.insert(23, &foo); ... but I'm not sure if the smart pointer counts this reference.

Comment: Bad idea. Will lead to crashes. Check my update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looked into QCache API, and since my guess is correct, I will post it as an answer (with hopes for upvotes!).

Signature for `insert()` is `bool QCache::insert(const Key & key, T * object, int cost = 1)`. Moreover, API mentions the fact that QCache owns the pointer from that moment on, so you do not need shared_ptr at all. Instead, you should insert raw pointer which will be managed by QCache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the help.

Comment: The problem is, that I have a vector of shared_ptr and I want to put part of them to my QCache. What happens if I set the pointer to my cache but destroy the vector and the shared pointer in it? WIll the memory be released and my cache points to nowhere?

Comment: @adapto, you will have a corrupted program if you try to do this. You can't have the same pointer owned by two managers - QCache and shared_ptr.

Comment: That caused the confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280524/qcache-and-qsharedpointer/