# QCache and QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers, qvector, qsharedpointer

The problem is, that I have a `QVector` of `QSharedPointer` and I want to put part of them to my `QCache`. How can I insert a shared pointer to `QCache`? What happens if I set the pointer to my cache but destroy the `QVector` and the shared pointer in it? Will the memory be released and my cache points to nowhere?

Comment: Shared pointers use reference counting, so nothing will get deleted by QSharedPointer until the last QSharedPointer pointing to it is destroyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug if you put just a pointer to your item to `QChache` and at the same time such pointer is managed by `QSharedPointer`. The item object can be destroyed by `QSharedPointer` destructor, so `QChache` will have invalid pointer. It is a generic issue that you cannot have different owners of a pointer that do not know each other. If you manage pointers by `QSharedPointer<Item>` then `QChache` should not work directly with `Item` it should work only with `QSharedPointer<Item>`, for example:

```
// wrong
QCache<int, Item> cache;
QVector<QSharedPointer<Item> > vec;
Item *item = new Item;
vec.push_back(QSharedPointer<Item>(item));
cache.insert(1, item);
// or
cache.insert(1, vec.at(0).data());

// also wrong
QCache<int, <QSharedPointer<Item> > cache;
vec.push_back(QSharedPointer<Item>(item));
cache.insert(1, new QSharedPointer<Item>(item));
// here two different instances of QSharedPointer are initialized
// by the same pointer 'item'

// correct
QCache<int, <QSharedPointer<Item> > cache;
cache.insert(1, new QSharedPointer<Item>(vec.at(0)));
```

So, `QCache` should have its own copy of dynamically allocated `QSharedPointer` object and that `QSharedPointer` object should be correctly initialized by other `QSharedPointer` that already has ownership of the `Item` instance.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. But in another thread someone told me not to use smart pointers with QCache. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33158035/5447060

Comment: @adapto That is because you did not mention in your question that the same object will be used outside of `QCache`. It is ok if you allocate a new object and then pass it to `QCache`, but in that case that pointer should not be owned by any other object.

Comment: But in this case no need for shared_ptr exists in QCache. OP can simply do this: `cache.insert(1, new Item(item));`

Comment: @SergeyA OP wants to keep those pointers in external vector, but `QCache` can delete items when it decides to make free place during insertion of new items, so pointers in that vector become invalid.

Comment: Right. So this is why there is no need to create another shared_ptr only to put it into the cache. Cache is a collection of shared_ptrs already, it manages them. Just an extra indirection.

Comment: Unfortunately `QCache` is rather container of unique_ptrs. So to share that pointer with external shared_prts there is no other solution than wrapping `QCache` managed item by shared_prt.